# combine 3d arrays into a 4d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 images of the same size, I read each one using [matplotlib.image.imread](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) which returns a 3D [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/) array.

```py
(Height, Width, ChannelsNumber) # ChannelsNumber = 3 for RGB
```

Now, i want to merge the 3 images into a 4D numpy array like this :

```py
(Height, Width, ChannelsNumber, NumberOfImages)
```

Meaning, the 3rd dimension array at position `(X,Y)` will no longer contain RGB values for pixel `(X,Y)` but will contain 3 arrays one for each channel (), where each array will contain 3 R, G, r B values  (for 3 images)

- array at position `X,Y,0` will contain all RED values for images `1,2,3` at pixel `X,Y`
- array at position `X,Y,1` will contain all GREEN values for images 1,2,3 at pixel `X,Y`
- array at position `X,Y,2` will contain all BLUE values for images 1,2,3 at pixel `X,Y`

For example :

`(10,15,0)` will be an array containing all the RED values for all the images for Pixel `(10,15)`

Here's what i have tried :

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img1 = mpimg.imread('./image1.jpg')
img2 = mpimg.imread('./image2.jpg')
img3 = mpimg.imread('./image3.jpg')

x = np.dstack((img1, img2, img3))
```

this returns a 3D array, where the 3rd dimension is an array that contains the RGB values of the images in this format:

```py
[R-img1, B-img1, G-img1, R-img2, B-img2, G-img2, R-img3, B-img3, G-img3]
```

where what i want is :

```py
[ 
    [R-img1, R-img2, R-img3,],
    [R-img1, B-img2, -img3,],
    [B-img1, B-img2, B-img3,]
]
```

Thank you !

Comment: .stack along axis=-1

Comment: @Scott thank you .. put this as an answer so that i mark this as answerd ..

Comment: x = np.vstack((img1, img2, img3))

Comment: @Scott how do i reverse, do the opposite, for output to input ?

Comment: The first img is the 0th element along the last index.  `img1 = stacked_imgs[...,0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is the one **Scott** commented

```py
x = np.stack((img1, img2, img3), axis = -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img1 = mpimg.imread('1.png')
img2 = mpimg.imread('2.png')
img3 = mpimg.imread('1.png')

print(img1.shape)
print(img2.shape)
print(img3.shape)
x = np.vstack((img1, img2, img3))
```

Stack arrays in sequence vertically